# ASP.NET request spending time in ACQUIRE_REQUEST_STATE

Tags: performance, session, iis-7, session-state

In View Currently Executing Requests in IIS7 I can see some requests in the `RequestAcquireState` with really high Time Elapsed, e.g. 7 seconds

If I understand correctly this means that 7 seconds were spent somewhere in the states below.

```
BEGIN_REQUEST
AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST
AUTHORIZE_REQUEST
RESOLVE_REQUEST_CACHE
MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER
ACQUIRE_REQUEST_STATE
```

We are using ASP.NET Sessions Server which is accessed over network by 3 Web Servers.
I heard about some potential locking issues that may arise.

Does anybody have any idea how to diagnose this further?

Thanks,
Piotr